# Eclipse : Errors occurred during the build

Tags: eclipse, build, eclipse-plugin

Every time I try to run my project as an Android Application this error shows up:

> Errors occurred during the build. Errors running builder 'Android
>   Package Builder' on project 'projectname'.
>   com/android/dx/command/dexer/Main : Unsupported major.minor version
>   52.0

Everything was fine before I shut down my laptop when a update came and i didn't wait until it ends. I toked of the power adapter from the wall and next day the laptop won't turn on. I formatted it then reinstalled Eclipse, JDK and SDK's and then this error shows up.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. [Read here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for more information about how to create a Minimal, Complete and Verifiable question.

Comment: Remove hysterical emotions and clear explanations.

Comment: @AlexKudryashev Good! :-) In similar cases I suggest them to read [this](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/291362/advice-for-non-native-english-speakers/291370#291370). After that, they disappear.